# drawAtPoint: and drawInRect: blurry text

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, fonts, font-size

When drawing strings using drawAtPoint:, drawInRect: and even setting the text property of UILabels - the text can sometimes appear slightly blurry.

I tend to use Helvetica in most places, and I notice that specific font sizes cause some level of blurriness to occur, both in the simulator and on the device.

For example:

```
UIFont *labelFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12];
```

Will cause the resulting label to have slightly blurry text.

```
UIFont *labelFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13];
```

Results in crisp text.

My question is why does this occur?  And is it just a matter of selecting an optimal font size for a typeface?  If so, what are the optimal font sizes?

UPDATE: It seems that perhaps it is not the font size that is causing the blurriness.  It may be that the center of the rect is a fractional point.  Here is a comment I found on the Apple dev forums:

> Check the position.  It's likely on a
>   fractional pixel.  Change center to be
>   integer value.

I rounded off the values of all my points, but there are still places where text remains blurry.  Has anyone come across this issue before?

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16822238/308315

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have resolved this.

Just make sure that the point or rect in which you are drawing does not occur on a fractional pixel.

I.e. `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(theRect))` to determine which point is being drawn on a fractional pixel.  Then call `round()` on that point.

Comment: the key to the problem is right, although rounding is not the best technique. A lot of rounds can actually shift or resize the frame. The best approach would be to store the original frame as a property and then set it back. That guarantees no shifts or resizes

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at NSIntegralRect(), it does what you want.

Comment: NSIntegralRect() is Mac only, not iOS.

Comment: You're right of course use [CGRectIntegral()](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectIntegral) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Pardon my ignorance if this is incorrect, I know nothing about iPhone or Cocoa.

If you're asking for the text to be centered in the rect, you might also need to make sure the width and/or height of the rect is an even number.

Comment: Thanks. I rounded all points and the width and height. Also rounded the points for the center property. Still no dice.

Answer (score 2):

I have had this problem too, but my solution is different and may help someone.
My problem was text blur after changing the size of a `UIView` object thru `TouchesBegan`
and `CGAffineTransformMakeScale`, then back to `CGAffineTransformIdentity` in `TouchesEnded`.

I tried both the varying text size and rounding of x and y center points but neither worked.
The solution for my problem was to use even sizes for the width and height of my `UIView` !!

Hope this helps ....

Answer (score 0):

From my experiments, some fonts don't render clearly at certain sizes.  e.g. Helvetica-Bold doesn't render "." well at 16.0f, but they're clear at 18.0f.  (If you look closely, the top pixel of the "." is blurry.)

After I noticed that, I've been irked every time I see that UIView, since it's rendered dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I drew text on a custom `CALayer` and turned out to be pretty blurry. I solved it by setting `contentScale` with appropriate value:

Objective-C:

```
layer.contentsScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
```

Swift:

```
layer.contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale
```